# How to calculate deflection of a cantilever beam subject to point loading

Tags: structural-engineering, beam, deflection

I am trying to solve the following beam deflection problem:

> The cantilever beam is subjected to the point load at C.
>
> 1. Generate the equation for the elastic curve by using the double integration method.
> 2. Find the maximum deflection and slope if L = 3 m and P = 10 kN acted at 2 m from A.
>
> [image: A cantilever beam is fixed on the left (point A). Force P is shown acting in the downward direction at the rightmost end of the beam (point C). The length of the beam is L.]
>
> **Ans:** $y_{max} = -46.67/{EI}$

For part 1, my answer is $EI\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} = - Px$.

For part 2, my answer is:
$$\begin{gather}
EI\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -\dfrac{Px^2}{2} +c_1 \\
EIy = -\dfrac{Px^3}{6} +c_1x +c2
\end{gather}$$

- at $x= 0$, $y = 0$, so $c_2 = 0$
- at $x = 0$ , $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 0$, so $c_1 = 0$

So, $EIy = -\dfrac{Px^3}{6}$.

$EIy$ max occurs at $L=3$, so $EIy_{max} = -\dfrac{10\cdot3^3}{6} = -45$, but the answer is  $EIy_{max} =-46.67$. What have I done wrong?

For the slope at x = 2, my answer is $EI\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -\dfrac{Px^2}{2} =  -\dfrac{10\cdot2^2}{2} = -\dfrac{40}{EI}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both answers are incorrect.

Your answer to (a) would imply that the bending moment is equal to zero at $x=0$ and increases linearly until $x=L$. This is only true if you put $x=0$ at the free end of the beam and $x=L$ at the fixed support, in which case you'd have to change your constraints. What you actually need is:

$$EI\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} = -PL + Px$$

For (b), you didn't notice that the behavior is different in such a beam. You can't simply use the equation above and be done with it. After all, this equation describes a beam under load, but the span from $x \in [2, 3]$ is not under load and therefore its beam equation is different (it follows a linear path).

The easy way to solve it is to start by finding the slope and deflection at $x=2$. For this, we can use the equation above:

$$\begin{gather}
EI\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -PLx + \dfrac{Px^2}{2} + c_1 \\
\dfrac{dy}{dx}(x=0) = 0 = c_1 \\
EIy = -\dfrac{PLx}{2} + \dfrac{Px^3}{6} + c_2 \\
y(x=0) = 0 = c_2 \\
\therefore EI\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -PLx + \dfrac{Px^2}{2} \\
\therefore EIy = -\dfrac{PLx^2}{2} + \dfrac{Px^3}{6}
\end{gather}$$

From which we gather that

$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{dy}{dx}(2) &= -\dfrac{20}{EI} \\
y(2) &= -\dfrac{26.667}{EI}
\end{align}$$

From $x = 2$ to $x = 3$, the deflection is linear, meaning that the slope is constant, so the result above for $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ is the same at $x=3$. Knowing this, we can find the deflection at $x=3$ by finding the linear component and then adding it to $y(2)$ (where $\ell$ is the linear span):

$$\begin{align}
\delta &= \dfrac{dy}{dx}(2)\cdot\ell = -\dfrac{26.667}{EI}\cdot1\\
\therefore y(3) &= y(2) + \delta = -\dfrac{46.667}{EI}
\end{align}$$

Comment: are you sure that y(4 ) = y(2) + $$\delta$$ ? in my working ? i found that y(2) = -46.67/EI directly without adding the $$\delta$$

Comment: @kelvinmacks: Why wouldn't it be? And in your original post you found 45, not 46.67, so I have no idea what you did. Another (equivalent) way of finding it would be to find the beam equation at $x \in [2,3]$ considering the initial conditions at $x=2$. But yes, since the deflection is linear at $x \in [2,3]$, one can just calculate the results at $x=2$ and then add the linear variation with the constant slope. And please [read the MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/88836) for how to write math here.

Comment: Can you explain why EI(d2y/dx2) = -PL+Px ?

Comment: @kelvinmacks: $EI\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is equal to the bending moment $M$. $M(x=0) = -PL$ and $M(x=L) = 0$ and it follows a linear diagram. That behavior is described by $EI\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = M = -PL+Px$. As I wrote in my answer, your answer of $M = -Px$ means $M(x=0) = 0$ and $M(x=L) = -PL$, which only makes sense if you put your origin ($x=0$) at the free end. But then your constraints are incorrect since they are at $x=0$, while they'd have to be at $x=L$ for your answer to work.

Comment: well , it's not possible to use x = 0 start from the P, right ? here's what i did , i let x = 0 start from P to x = L ends at the fixed support ... So, EI(d2y/dx2) = -Px , EI(dy/dx) = -P(x^2)/2  +c1 ,  EI(y) = -P(x^3)/6 + c1x +c2 , when x = 0 , y = 0 , so , c2 = 0 , x = 0 , dy/dx = 0 , so c1 = 0 , when x = 1 , which means 2m from A , 1m from B , i have EI(y) = -P(x^3)/6 = -10(1^3) /6 = -1.67 , but the ans is -46.67, which part of my working is wrong ?

Comment: @kelvinmacks: I read your answer, I know what you did, no need to repeat it all here. The problem there is that you set $x=0$ at the load, but then you put the constraints at $x=0$ as well ("when x = 0 , y = 0", "x = 0 , dy/dx = 0"), when they would then have to be at $x=L$ instead (so $y(x=L)=0$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}(x=L) = 0$).

Comment: so what's wrong with the ans ?

Comment: @kelvinmacks: I've already told you what's wrong with your answer. Twice. Explicitly. I suggest you take some time to carefully read my answer and study it. If you can't see what is wrong after my explicit descriptions, then I honestly don't what else I can do for you.

Comment: " But then your constraints are incorrect since they are at x=0x=0, while they'd have to be at x=Lx=L for your answer to work" do you mean that it is a must to involve x = L in this case ? sorry , English is my 2nd language , my english is not so good

Comment: Sorry ,  can  you  explain  further ?  I still  don't  understand

Comment: so , it's not possible to use EI(d2y/dx2)  = -Px in this question(although x is measured from the right end) ? it's a must to use  EI(d2y/dx2)  = -PL +Px ?

Comment: why we need to add $$\delta$$ to y(2) ? for deflection , we just need y(2) , right ?