# What is the formula for deflection of an end-loaded cantilever rod beam?

Tags: beam, deflection

For a cantilever beam of circular cross section, loaded at the end, how does the deflection of the free end vary as a function of beam length and diameter?

I expect the answer will be something like:

$$\dfrac{L^2}{D^3}$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate deflection of a cantilever beam subject to point loading](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12538/how-to-calculate-deflection-of-a-cantilever-beam-subject-to-point-loading)

Comment: Not as far as my math skills go.

Comment: Amount of deflection at end of beam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a cantilever with a point load at the free end, the deflection at that free end is:

$$\dfrac{WL^3}{3EI}$$

<sup>Handbook of Structural Steelwork - 3rd edition</sup>

where

- $W$ = point load
- $L$ = beam length
- $E$ = Young's modulus
- $I$ = second moment of area

The Young's modulus depends on the material, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young's_modulus#Approximate_values) for various examples.

The second moment of area for a circle is:

$$\dfrac{\pi r^4}{4} = \dfrac{\pi d^4}{64}$$

So your overall equation is:

$$\dfrac{64WL^3}{3\pi Ed^4}$$